# Identify similar amounts

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to develop a scrip that read a series of amounts and then identify which amount correspond with the approximately amount that I have.

For instance, I want to find a way that the script make an approximately match with the amount of: **150.38**

```
100.00 
150.50 #this would be the match 
200.38 
240.00 
300.25
```

How can I make the script understand that these amounts are "equal"?

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts? Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with code so we can better understand how to help. For example, the [round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function seems applicable

Comment: "How can I make the script understand that these amounts are "equal"?" In your own words, **why is it**? What does "approximately" mean to you? It is only possible to implement rules that have actually been figured out.

Comment: "hen identify which amount correspond with the approximately amount that I have." Think carefully about the implications of saying "which amount". Do you mean that there will *always* be a value you want to choose? Do you mean that *only one* value can be chosen? If so - could it be that what you really want is the *closest* value? Also: *what does this question have to do with Pandas*? If it doesn't, then please don't use the tag. If your "series of amounts" is a `pandas.Series`, then please explicitly say so in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your case, you can find the absolute relative distance of  the floating numbers and find the first occurrence of the minimum distance and display:

```
dist = (df['numbers'] - closest_to).abs()
dist.idxmin()
closest = df.iloc[dist.idxmin()]
```

**Complete example:**

```
#creating dataframe
data = {'numbers':[100.00,150.50,200.38,240.00,300.25]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(float)

#setting closest value
closest_to = 150.38 

#find closest
dist = (df['numbers'] - closest_to).abs()
dist.idxmin()
closest = df.iloc[dist.idxmin()]

closest
```

**Outputs:**

```
numbers    150.5
Name: 1, dtype: float64
```